# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 450 - Java

Tags: java

I am just trying to learn Java and "one" of my mistakes in the code is an OutOfBounds-Error but I don't see why. Maybe someone can give me a litte hint.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 450
    at Salary.main(Salary.java:17)

```
public class Salary {
private static int taxClass;

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // list of salaries pre tax
    int[] salariesPreTax = new int[] { 450, 800, 1235, 2200, 2458, 3125, 3300, 4100, 4278, 5001, 5222, 5783, 6100, 14750, 18875, 20470 };

    double[] salariesAfterTax = new double [15];

    for ( int i : salariesPreTax) {
        int value = salariesPreTax[i];
        salariesAfterTax[i] = calculateSalary(value, getTaxClass(value));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<salariesAfterTax.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" Salary after tax: " +salariesAfterTax[i] );
    }
} 


private static double calculateSalary(final int value, final int taxClass) {

    double valueAfterTax = -1.0d;

    switch (taxClass) {             
    case 1:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 1);   
        break;
    case 2:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.945);
        break;
    case 3:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.88);
        break;
    case 4:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.82);
        break;
    case 5:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.7975);
        break;
    case 6:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.7425);
        break;
    case 7:                         
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.645);
        break;
    default:                        
        valueAfterTax = (value * 0.985);
        break;
    }   

    return valueAfterTax;
}

private static int getTaxClass(final int salaryPreTax) {

    if (salaryPreTax < 800) {
        return 1;
    }

        if (salaryPreTax >= 800 && salaryPreTax < 1200) {
        return 2;
    }

        if (salaryPreTax >= 1200 && salaryPreTax < 2100) {
        return 3;
    }

        if (salaryPreTax >= 2100 && salaryPreTax < 3000) {
        return 4;
    }

    if (salaryPreTax >= 3000 && salaryPreTax < 3800) {
        return 5;
    }

        if (salaryPreTax >= 3800 && salaryPreTax < 5000) {
        return 6;
    }

    if (salaryPreTax >= 5000) {
        return 7;
    }


    return taxClass;
}
} // end class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `i` in

```
for ( int i : salariesPreTax) {
    int value = salariesPreTax[i];
```

is already the value of an element of the array, not an index of the array (and you can see that in the exception, which contains `450` - the first value in your array).

So to iterate over the values of the array, all you need is :

```
for (int value : salariesPreTax) {
    ...
```

However, since you also want to modify the array, you need the indices, so you should use the regular for loop, which iterates over the indices :

```
for (int i = 0; i < salariesPreTax.length; i++) {
    int value = salariesPreTax[i];
    salariesAfterTax[i] = calculateSalary(value, getTaxClass(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i : you-array)
```

This is already returns a value, so don't try to pull any value from it.

Directly use it likewise:

```
... = CalculateSalary(i,....);
}
```